# Win10 Sytems Recovery from System Image Installs Prior Image Config

Tags: windows-10, system-recovery

Windows 10-1703 on the "Current Branch for Business" with feature updates delayed 365 days (disabled). Build 15063.1266

I create system images to protect against drive failures, (disastrous feature updates), etc. After filling my 128G drive I was restoring from a image written to a USB connected hard drive which had images from 5/9/18 and 8/19/18. I expected to see the 8/19/18 image chosen to restore, but it was not listed anywhere, instead the 5/9/18 image was the only image shown.

So dutifully, I chose to select image, then hoping the USB drive would be scanned and all images listed, but no joy, the 5/9/18 image was the only one shown. So I left in select and chose "Next" and let the image install (which it did just fine). Installed AOMEI partition assistant, moved the 850M backup partition to the end of the free space, expanded the original partition to fill the 256G drive, and was good to go.

The problem is there are now 3 months of updates missing (MS as well as all other programs), and 3 months of work gone. I have backups, that's not the issue, the issue is "Why am I having to use them when they were imaged on 8/19/18?" and "Why did recovery only list the 5/9/18 image when the 8/19/18 image was present?

After restoring the 5/9/18 image, and updating windows, the mozilla apps, libre office, etc.., I decided to look at the USB drive to find out why it installed the 5/9 image. The disk itself contains the 8/19 image, which is what prompted this question. E.g. the USB Drive being restored from contained:

> "E:\WindowsImageBackup\elite\Backup 2018-08-19 053450"
>
> All files 13e581ce-0000-0000-.... 8/19/18

How do I get the recovery disk to install the 8/19/18 image instead of restore the image as it was on 5/9? Since all the image files are dated 8/19/18 (literlly the actual images, e.g. the 7G and 33G actual image files are all dated 8/19, there are only a few xml files that still have the 5/9 date.

Anybody seen this? Anybody have a solution?

Here is an image of the contents of the USB drive containing the 8/19/18 image:

[image]

There are no other directories under `elite` (the hostname for the HP Elitebook).

**Edit With Full Contents of Win10 Image**

I got back into my comfort zone and can now easily show the entire contents of the windows 10 image files. There is just one `Medaild` file and most of the `SPPMetadatCache` cache files that are 5/9/18. **All** `.vhdx` files are dated 8/19/18. Sorry for the image and not text (I can provide that too), but the image captured the data in an easily viewable format.

[image]

The remaining files shown under the hostname *SKYLAKE_J* are not relevant. Those are from an old Win7 install and shouldn't be (and were not) listed as part of the backup.

With all the actual `.vhdx` files dated 8/19, it does look like some strange restore the 8/19 data and rollback to 5/9 took place. I do like the suggestion that it may be possible to mount and then recover the 8/19 files, but while I'm quite fluent with mounting in Linux, dealing with the `.vhdx` files on windows is something I have not yet enjoyed.

The articles I have read suggest moving the contents of the backup under `WindowsImageBackup`, but to the uneducated eye -- that looks like where they were to begin with -- so that doesn't quite fit the circumstance.

I welcome any other thoughts or ideas here. Other than deducing (guessing at) what happened, given what I saw from the recover software, the result of restoring the image and the dates on the files -- I have long since exhausted my understanding of why the system was restored to 5/9 instead of 8/19.

Comment: We’d have to assume that something must’ve gone wrong during the backup. But that’s going to be hard to know now. The Vhd files are what hold the actual data from the partitions on your computer. You could feasibly just mount and copy them over to blank partitions using a cloning tool or something like that - search for vhd to physical disk solutions. On another note, you could probably just rename and move the vhd files around so that Windows installs the newer vhd files even though it thinks it’s installing the 5-9 files, if that makes sense. One or more vhd files may be corrupt.

Comment: Yes, thanks. Its like the recovery software saw the index for the 5/9 image, used the 8/19 data files, but then rolled the system back to match the 5/9 image -- really bizarre -- because there are no other image files that Windows 10 could have been restored from on the USB drive. The only files over 1G are dated 8/19. I still have the drive I imaged from. I think I'll boot that, roll back to 1703 from 1803 which has sound issues (I'm still in my 10 days) and do a disk cleanup and re-image to a fresh 1T drive -- that way there can be no confusion by the recovery software.

Comment: @Appleoddity - I used the recovery disk from about a year ago rather than burning another CD (I have about 6 of them) I used to make them each time I did an image, but then figured I had enough. Is there a possibility the recovery software written to the CD changed in the last year so as to make finding the 8/19 image impossible but able to see the 5/9 index (I'm grasping at straws here -- I don't do a lot with windows)

Comment: I could probably make this work but I’m not real familiar with it to talk you through it. Are you saying those are the only large vhd files on the drive? Then what you have is an “original” image followed by snapshots. Together it forms a complete, up to date image but allows you to roll back to previous versions of “snapshots.” So like you have a base image and two snapshots at different dates. I’m not sure why it doesn’t see the proper one. You can mount the vhd file and see what files are on the “drive” and if they are up to date. If so, the images might be good and you can go from there.

Comment: @Appleoddity - I think you are on to something. There are only 8/19 `.vhdx` files on the system image. I have updated the question showing the complete contents of the backup for `elite` (the `SKYLAKE_J` backups are Win7 and shouldn't interfere). Give it a look and I welcome your thoughts.

Comment: As a note, I did rollback the original drive the image came from which I had moved to 1803. It is now happily back to 1703 with virtually no fuss, and all the weird 1803 issues like the keyboard focus stuck somewhere blocking [Enter] being used to bring up login. Icons no longer move on the desktop, etc... So I have the original drive that the image was made from if a reimage is needed for comparison.